# Export settings with enabled sychronization

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I would like to export some settings (especially Live Templates to share with my colleagues), but the "Export Settings" button is not available with enabled sychronization.

When I disable sync, the buttons appears again, but my Live Templates stored in the JetBrains account are not available anymore.

**My question**: Is there a way to export settings with enabled sychronization?

**NOTE** I also opened a ticket on [intellij-support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004555580-Export-settings-with-enabled-sychronization-).

Comment: Watch after and check comments in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202548 -- it has comments from JetBrains stuff with how it can be done manually.

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for the hint. Didn't find that.

Comment: Try those "workarounds" (comments made by JetBrains personnel). If it work for you -- consider answering your own question with exact steps you did -- will help others in similar situation (until that issue is properly resolved).

Answer (score 0):

I got an comment on my Ticket which was quite useful:

> To export templates, just copy /jba_config/templates folder to preferred location; you can then copy this folder to the config directory of the IDE you'd like importing it to

In my case the templates where located under *C:\Users\myUserName\.WebStorm2019.2\config\jba_config\templates\myLiveTemplates.xml*